# How do I integrate the FB Javascript API with custom database

Tags: database, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, single-sign-on, facebook-login

I am new to `Facebook` development.

Is it possible to have a website login with `Facebook` + a `non-FB` `database`?

Specifically I would like my users to access `Facebook` information similar to `Sociogram` (http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/02/sociogram-a-sample-application-exploring-the-facebook-sdk-and-the-graph-api/) which I have gotten working with my own website `app`, but also tie in additional user information that `Facebook` does not keep - so that my users only have to have one login.

Any info on where to start researching would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are talking about having your own database, i can guide you like this.

1. Use facebook javascript login to get premissions from user and save them to your database in which you may have other details to be added later for your website purpose
2. When you save details once from first login, you dont need to save them on next login. So Write code so that on first login check your database for user existance and if not then add him to database.
3. And in that database you can add extra field that facebook wont save like his height for example.

For this to happen you must have server side scripting knowledge to store the details to database. If you need further more details, i am here to answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is great for me to get started researching.

Comment: I have been researching this, and having difficulty finding a starting point that works (lots of tutorials online that don't work!). I was able to get an AJAX tutorial to log the user in to FB + post that data to MySQL, but it seems to only work for the first user who logs in. Do you know why this solution would not be working? http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-facebook-connect-with-jquery-php

Comment: Make sure your app is not in sandbox mode. because in sandbox mode only developper can test the app. You can upload the code and give me link. I can tell you where you made a mistake. Just send me i will tell you the error. :)